# Wrong subpath with end intersection points

Tags: asymptote

Apologies upfront for cross-posting. I've posted the same question in asymptote discussion forums.

I'm trying to find out the outline of two intersecting triangles. I'm expecting the outline of star-shaped figure.

My code is below

```
import geometry;
import math;
unitsize(1cm);

point a = (2.5,4);
point b = (0,0);
point c = (5,0);
triangle t1 = triangle(a,b,c);
triangle t2 = shift(5,3)*rotate(180)*t1;

path abc = t1.Path();
path cba = t2.Path();
real[][] arr = intersections(abc,cba);

path[] sp;

sp = sp^^subpath(abc,arr[1][0],arr[2][0]);
sp = sp^^subpath(abc,arr[3][0],arr[4][0]);
sp = sp^^subpath(abc,arr[5][0],arr[0][0]);

draw(t1,lightgray);
draw(t2,lightgray);
draw(sp,red);
```

I'm trying to create a subpath from the intersections of two paths. The subpath creation is correct until I reach the last of the intersection points. The 3rd subpath line in the above code is messing up the subpath. What is going wrong here?

Comment: "asymptote discussion forums."? If you mean a site that is not SE, then it's not "cross-posted" in the sense that it's usually meant by that (i.e. across the SE network). So don't worry about it.

Comment: The problem is the way `subpath` works: if you place the greater time first, then it implicitly reverses the order (although it also switches the path orientation). In your case, you can make it do the right thing by changing the last line to `sp = sp^^subpath(abc,arr[5][0], length(abc) + arr[0][0]);`.